# Disk iops vs latency

Tags: performance, storage, latency, iops

I am trying to understand the diference between iops and latency, this is my question:

If an hypothetical disk had 2 io per second, then its latency would be 0.5 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to understand the diference between iops and latency, this is my question:
>
> If an hypothetical disk had 2 io per second, then its latency would be 0.5 seconds?

- **IOPS** is the number of I/O operations completed per-second
- **Latency** implies there's a **delay** before IO completes not only due its volume (amount of data is being sent) but even when it's absolute minimal data requested. Thus it's kinda penalty *each* separate IO operation incurs *except the transfer time itself* — which is **bandwidth** dependent.

Let's get back to:

> If an hypothetical disk had 2 io per second, then its latency would be 0.5 seconds?

Hopefully, now it's clear that the answer here is "it could be". Because if each I/O was lengthy (latency 0.1 + sending data 0.4 sec) it's obviously them 2 would need totally 1 second to complete but by definition (formula) latency was just 0.1 sec. OTOH, if you know that no matter how minimal was the data transfer, but only 2 IOPS completed, then, yeah, it's latency 0.5 sec.

P. S. Similar things happen in Networking domain, BTW. You run `ping` with some minimal data length possible and get estimation of channel's latency, then you increase its length or download big enough file with `curl` and figure out channel's bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean fully loaded disk and it shows at best 2 iops, we can say *average* latency is 0.5 seconds.

If you were analyzing some performance data of a running system which shows that during some stretch of the time the disk handled 2 iops, it is not so easy. Disk might be completing its I/O quickly (with low latency) and then sitting idle the rest of the time because there are no requests to serve. If there were more I/O load, it might have been shown more iops. The only thing we can say in this case is that its *average* latency is *at most* 0.5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

IOPS isn't latency.

IOPS is the number of operations per second; as the number of IOPS requested from the device increases the latency will increase.

Imagine your disk is 2 IOPS. If you send 2 requests simultaneously, this will average 1 second to complete. If you send 20 requests near simultaneously, this will take ten seconds to complete, so any extra requests will have a latency of 10 seconds, because they are waiting for the others to complete.

Simplified, but a good example.

Comment: So, the latency depends on the size of the queue? If queue's size is zero, latency per iop is 0.5 seconds, if queue's size > 0, latency = 0.5 + 0.5*queueSize?

Comment: As the queue grows yes you will more latency as the server can only do so many requests per second. You will have some latency anyway even with no requests in the queue.